# Simpler way to find solution of equation

Tags: math, matlab, equation-solving

I have following equation:

```
f(N):  N = ((1+lam)^3 )/ ((1-lam)*(1+lam^2));
```

I need to create a function that finds `lam` for specified `N`.

Right now I'm doing it using simple loop:

```
lam = 0.9999;
n = f(lam);
pow = 0;
delta = 0.1;
while(abs(N - n)) > 0.1 & pow < 10000)
    lam = lam - 0.001;
    n = f(lam)
    pow = pow+1;
end
```

How can I solve it more accurate and without using loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have

```
N = ((1+lam)^3 )/ ((1-lam)*(1+lam^2))
```

then you know that

```
(1+lam)^3 = N*(1-lam)*(1+lam^2)
```

Suppose you were to expand these terms? Coalesce into one simple cubic equation, with real coefficients, equal to zero? Is there a function that will solve it for you?

The answer is yes. One solution might be to use fzero, but since the equation is just a cubic polynomial, roots is the answer unless you needed a symbolic solution. Use the symbolic toolbox for symbolic problems.

Comment: Or just put the equation in Maxima (free) and ask it to solve for lam.

Comment: Thanks, `fzero` does the job quite nicely :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for N=10 by Wolfram Alpha:

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx^3)/((1-x)*(1%2Bx^2))%3D10
```

An algebraic solution will work for your particular case, because it's not terribly difficult.  The problem is that, in general, non-linear equations require an iterative solution: start with a guess, step in a particular direction, and hopefully converge to a solution.  You can't solve non-linear equations in general *without* iteration and looping.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the equation to be `0 = f(x)/g(x)` (where `f` and `g` are polynomials).  Then solve for `0 = f(x)`.  This should be easy enough as `f` will be cubic (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function).  In fact, Matlab has the `roots()` function to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Plotting suggest that for N positive, there is exactly one solution in the interval [-1,1). You should consider [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method), it will converge for a zero initial guess fairly quickly.

Comment: In fact, there should always be exactly one solution in the interval (0, 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this equation in closed form, as discussed in other answers, but to be honest, closed-form solutions to polynomials of degree > 2 are not very useful in practice, because the results tend to be poorly conditioned.

For your particular polynomial, I agree with Alexandre that Newton's method is probably the way to go.

In the long run, though, I highly recommend writing (or reusing from the Internet) an implementation of the Jenkins-Traub root-finding algorithm. Wikipedia describes it as "practically a standard in black-box polynomial root-finders," and they're not exaggerating. It has served all of my polynomial-solving needs for years; in my experience it's more robust than Newton's method (no reliance on a good initial guess) and eigenvalue-based methods, and is quite fast to boot.

Comment: I can second the fact that the closed form solvers are not very numerically stable beyond 2 or 3 degrees.

FYI there is an open source c++ implementation (BSD license) of the Jenkins-Traub algorithm called [RPOLY++](https://github.com/sweeneychris/RpolyPlusPlus)

Answer (score 0):

There is an algebraic solution to your problem for most values of N. Here is the solution, as solved by [Wolfram Alpha](http://tinyurl.com/388vx9j):

```
if N+1!=0
   x = (20 N^3+18 N^2+3 sqrt(3) sqrt(16 N^6+32 N^5-20 N^4-72 N^3-9 N^2+54 N+27)-27 N-27)^(1/3)/(3 2^(1/3) (N+1))-(2^(1/3) (2 N^2+3 N))/(3 (N+1) (20 N^3+18 N^2+3 sqrt(3) sqrt(16 N^6+32 N^5-20 N^4-72 N^3-9 N^2+54 N+27)-27 N-27)^(1/3))+N/(3 (N+1))
```

Yes, it's ugly.

If you have one, an exact algebraic solution, even a big ugly one like this one, is always superior to a numerical solution. As duffymo indicated, solving a problem with numerical methods require iterations (so it's slow), and the solver can get stuck in local minima.

Comment: I bet $10 that Newton's method with a carefully chosen initial guess is faster than this.

Comment: I'd be very surprised, as this is relatively efficient despite being ugly. But I would be happy to be proven wrong.